# Understanding Symfony/mailer: why can't I found Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface in Vendors?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to figure out something I couldn't understand while exploring Symfony/Mailer source code.

At first I created a whole new project using these commands:

```
symfony new my_project_name --version=lts
```

```
composer require symfony/mailer
```

Then, when I was exploring the `Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\AbstractHttpTransport` and saw
it was using `Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface`.

I was surprised to find out that the `HttpClientInterface` is not part of my project, I can't find it anywhere and neither does PhpStorm.

How is this possible? Is that a programming trick I am not aware of?

I searched on the internet and find out about Symfony/Contracts project and its purpose but I don't understand how it can be declared in the project and not being part of it.

Here is a part of the source code of the AbstractHttpTransport in Symfony/mailer

```php
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;

...

abstract class AbstractHttpTransport extends AbstractTransport
{

   public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $client = null, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher = null, LoggerInterface $logger = null)

...
```

Edit: As required here is the composer.json generated for the project

```
{
"type": "project",
"license": "proprietary",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/mailer": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*"
},
"require-dev": {
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"replace": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
},
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
"conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "require": "4.4.*"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share the code lines of using the `HttpClientInterface` in `AbstractHttpTransport` class?

Comment: Sure they can be found in source code at https://github.com/symfony/mailer/blob/master/Transport/AbstractHttpTransport.php
Line 19 for the `use` and Line 31 in the `__construct` method

Comment: Symfony/contracts is a requirement for Mailer. You can see it [here](https://github.com/symfony/mailer/blob/master/composer.json). The contracts classes reside in your vendor folder, and were installed when you required Mailer. If they weren't (which is unlikely, but can happen), reinstall the component.

Comment: Sorry, but all I can see in your link, is a dependency on `symfony/service-contracts`, and it does not contain the HttpClientInterface I'm searching.
Did I miss your point ?

Comment: The contract interface lives in vendor/symfony/http-client-contracts Don't know why you were having trouble finding it.  My PHPStorm picked it right up.

Comment: Well the `symfony/http-client-contracts` is a dev dependency of Symfony/Mailer indeed. When I  build a new symfony project  with symfony/mailer dependency, a `composer install`command does not create a vendor/symfony/http-client-contracts folder with the code.
Did you use a different way to create the project than the one I described ?

Comment: Again, have you tried removing and reinstalling Mailer? It should have been installed the first time, if it wasn't retrying will very likely fix it.

Comment: Sorry I tried
`composer remove symfony/mailer`
`composer require symfony/mailer`
but it does not make appear the interface

Comment: That makes the question more interesting.  I was originally looking at an existing 4.4 project created using the --full option.  I followed your steps and got neither http-client nor the http-client-contracts directory.  "composer require symfony/http-client" will resolve this issue.  I'm guessing the client would normally be installed when you install a transport component.

Comment: Please update your post with your full `composer.json` so we can determine what dependencies your project is using and recreate the issue.

Comment: The http-client is optional. Even when you install specific mailer transports like `symfony/mailer-sendgrid` it will not necessarily install the http client as these components usually allow for other ways to send a mail that might not require an HTTP-Client. At least that's what it looks like from quickly browsing through the existing mailer-* packages. Since both http-client and the corresponding contracts are only dev requirements inside the package (not in your project) they will not be installed. You will have to require them manually.

Comment: @fyrye I added the composer.json, hope it helps.

Comment: remove your composer.lock and try composer install again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are unable to find `HttpClientInterface`, is that you do not require  any library that provides a `symfony/http-client-implementation`.

To allow a transport to use [`symfony/http-client`](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/http_client.html) you will need to explicitly install and [configure](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/configuration/framework.html#http-client) it.

```
composer require symfony/http-client
```

```
# config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    # ...
    http_client:
        max_host_connections: 10
        default_options:
            headers: { 'X-Powered-By': 'ACME App' }
            max_redirects: 7
```

---

> I don't understand how it can be declared in the project and not being
>   part of it.

You are able to declare any fully qualified namespace within a PHP application, without the subsequent class or file existing. Example: https://3v4l.org/RIWqS

```php
namespace Foo;

use Non\Existing\NamespaceClass;

class Bar
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo NamespaceClass::class;
    }
}

new \Foo\Bar(); //Non\Existing\NamespaceClass
```

Symfony has the capability to ignore autowired arguments that declare a service namespace that does not exist, and will instead supply `null` for its value.

### Clarification

[`symfony/mailer`](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/mailer.html) is a modular component, that does not require the Symfony Framework or the `symfony/http-client` in order to be used and can be used in virtually any application. Since the mailer can support a variety of different transports and those transports different clients, the code is included to work with them, but they are not a dependency for the mailer package. Allowing you to choose the transports you want to use.

In this instance, extending the `AbstractHttpTransport` will also require a service that implements the `Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface` to be provided or overridden. This allows for the `HttpClientInterface` to be used when it is available.

Symfony Framework specifically looks for the configuration for `http_client` and will configure the services that can utilize it for you. [[sic]](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/4.4/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php#L318) Once `symfony/http-client` is installed and configured, a transport that supports it, will utilize it for the connection.

### Source

The `HttpClientInterface` is supplied in `symfony/http-client-contracts`. Where a library that provides the implementation, will specify as such in the composer.json as `"provide": { "symfony/http-client-implementation": "*" }`. Such as [`symfony/http-client`](https://github.com/symfony/http-client/blob/4.4/composer.json)

Which is why no classes within `symfony/mailer` package `extends AbstractHttpTransport`, as it is intended to be used by other libraries, such as [`symfony/amazon-mailer`](https://github.com/symfony/amazon-mailer/blob/4.4/Transport/SesHttpTransport.php). While `symfony/mailer` does not provide the implementation for `symfony/http-client`, multiple classes and methods reference `HttpClientInterface`, allowing it to be used when available.

For more information see [Symfony Contracts](https://github.com/symfony/contracts/blob/master/README.md) and [Symfony Http Client](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-httpclient-component)

### Usage

The various [transports](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/mailer.html#transport) that `symfony/mailer` supports need to be added as desired by you. By default the only transport `symfony/mailer` comes pre-installed with is `SMTP`. Where other transports that support the `symfony/http-client` features **but do not require it**, are also available.